# Python - Randomly change picture without altering the picture quality

Tags: python, image-processing

I am using a system that doesn't allow multiple uploads of the same image. But I would like to use the same image multiple times. Since I have knowledge in Python,
I would like to create a script that basically randomly changes pictures without altering too much the quality of the image.

Do you know a library or a script that can do this?

thanks,

Comment: Why can't you upload it once and use it multiple times?

Comment: @superbrain thank you for your question. It is not possible to use it multiple times while uploading.  But I also like the challlenge.

Comment: Best library to deal with images in python is PIL (pillow)